# What is the difference between Firefox instance opened by Selenium WebDriver and the browser instance opened manually?

Tags: javascript, css, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I am automating an web application using Selenium WebDriver. This application is supposed to run on both ipad and desktop browser. While testing the automation scripts I found a strange behavior where, selecting a option from a drop-down list causes the page element to hide under floating menu. However this behavior is not seen on browser opened by running firefox.exe manually. The same behavior is seen in Internet Explorer 11 launched by selenium.

I had searched through internet for the possible causes but did not get any relevant justification for this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running tests using Selenium on any browser (in your case fire fox) it will have its own browser capabilities, preferences (profile configuration properties). If you want to maintain same configurations as that of manually opened (default) fire fox, create a profile (say sel_user) and and set preferences as that of default preferences. Pass this profile to the firefoxdriver to use it. some thing like as below...

```
...   
   ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
   FirefoxProfile fp = profile.getProfile("sel_user");
   fp.setPreference("browser.startup.homepage", "http://google.com");
   FirefoxDriver fd = new FirefoxDriver(fp);
...
```

Hope this helps.